# Add component via service to other component

Tags: angular

I have created a modal service that opens a view. What I want is that I can call an .open function and give a component as parameter. That component must be added then to the container view that is being openend.

My modalservice:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {

  private display: BehaviorSubject<'open' | 'close'> = new BehaviorSubject('close');

  watch(): Observable<'open' | 'close'> {
    return this.display.asObservable();
  }

  open(ref: ViewContainerRef): void {
    this.display.next('open');
  }

  close(): void {
    this.display.next('close');
  }
}
```

The modal component:

```
export class CustomModalComponent implements OnInit {

  display$: Observable<'open' | 'close'>;
  
  constructor(
    private modalService: ModalService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.display$ = this.modalService.watch();
  }

  close(): void {
    this.modalService.close();
  }
}
```

And the html:

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="display$ | async as display">
    
    <aside [ngClass]="this.display === 'open' ? '' : 'hidden'" class="fixed inset-0 z-50 flex" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">

// i want to add a custom view here
     </aside>
    </ng-container>
```

The view is opening correctly when I call this.modalService.open(). The last question is how can I give a custom view/ component to the open function what is displayed in the modal view. I did try some thing with a container ref, but with no luck.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this. https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#single-slot-content-projection

Comment: @da1lbi3 Do you still looking for this ? and Will you explain more about your use-case ?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding this custom modal component the view with the component html like this:

Some Components

```
<div> 
<app-custom-modal></app-custom-modal>
</div>
```

So you can do like pass the html by adding  it between those tag's then it can be used it to rendered the custom view like this

```
<div> 
<app-custom-modal> Passing a component <app-new+></app-new></app-custom-modal>
</div>
```

And then in Custom modal component show it using ng content tag

```
<ng-container *ngIf="display$ | async as display">
    
    <aside [ngClass]="this.display === 'open' ? '' : 'hidden'" class="fixed inset-0 z-50 flex" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">

// i want to add a custom view here
<ng-content></ng-content>
     </aside>
    </ng-container>
```

This will work

Comment: The problem is that I have the <app-custom-modal> in my main component, while I want to use it from other components.